# Remotely & Programmatically check document in and out

Tags: document-library, check-out, check-in

Here's the situation:

We have a number of Excel based tools that are checked into a SharePoint document library.  I want a program that will allow me to check out one to many tools, perform maintenance on each one (executing macros inside the tool, etc), then check the tool(s) back in.  I need assistance with programmatically checking in and out of the remote SharePoint server.

Requirements:
CLIENT side execution to remote server
VS2010/C#

Any and all help would be most appreciated.

Regards,
John E.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using SP 2010, then the client object model would be best.  Here's a link to a similar question on another forum:  http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010programming/thread/841ddb4b-1c8f-4d2b-b154-437ab4a7e2dc/

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I took a look at the link you provided, but it doesn't have any sample code or explaination.  There's only a PowerShell script snippet.  Am I missing something?

Comment: That was one example.  The Client Object Model can be done in C#, JavaScript, or Silverlight.  So no, they did not include code examples for all of the available code languages but you should be able to take what they have and easily convert it to the language that you need to utilize.  See here for the official documentation:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee537247.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the information. I was able to get the check in/out working in C#.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I was able to get the check in/out working in C#. – Falconeer Jun 26 '12 at 14:37 Care to share your code? thanks...